# How do I use a captured Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire, pokemon-third-generation

I just started playing Omega Ruby and it has been years since I've played.
After I catch a pokemon that goes into my pokedex, how to I transfer it into my lineup so I can use it in battles?

Answer (score 13):

You have a couple of options that can happen:

1. If you have less than **6** Pokemon in your party, any captured *Pokemon* will automatically be added into your party.
2. If you have **6** Pokemon in your party, any captured *Pokemon* will be transferred to your *PC*. You can access your *PC* at any *Pokemon Center*.

If the *Pokemon* is automatically added to your party, you will need to take them to the *Pokemon Center* to heal them. *Pokemon* taken out of the *PC* are already fully healed

Comment: Note: This is the same behavior as every other main line Pokemon game for the past 20 years.

Comment: @jpmc26 Pokemon games have really been around that long? Geez I feel old

Comment: I felt exactly the same way when I realized that.

Comment: @jpmc26 Except now you don't have to worry about having a full PC box. There's a little nostalgia nightmare for you Gen 1'ers.

Comment: @jpmc26 technically the first-gen games didn't heal the Pokemon when they were withdrawn from the box though

Comment: I suppose I should have said, "nearly the same behavior." ;)

Comment: @jpmc26 In case you didn't know, Pokemon will be celebrating it's 20th anniversary Feb. 7th, 2016.